# Not Able To Build ASP.net Core (2.1) in Azure DevOps? Why am I getting a main not exposed when it is (and it works in local iis and kestrel)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I am experiencing MASSIVE issues trying to configure a pipeline to deploy my ASP.net CORE 2.1 app -- it runs locally and on my production server without issue but will not build in azure devops (the default .net core build pipeline)

I am getting the following error -

> 2018-11-30T12:48:33.7773082Z CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [D:\a\4\s\RecipeSavants.Services\RecipeSavants.Services.csproj] 2018-11-30T12:48:33.7774419Z 0 Warning(s) 2018-11-30T12:48:33.7774665Z 1 Error(s) 2018-11-30T12:48:33.7774835Z 2018-11-30T12:48:33.7775041Z Time Elapsed 00:00:14.10 2018-11-30T12:48:33.8262171Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1 2018-11-30T12:48:33.8270669Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\4\s\RecipeSavants.Services\RecipeSavants.Services.csproj

Which is very strange - since this work like a champ locally on on my live IIS box -- it only fails in azure -- here is the error, my main, my project settings, and the output of running dotnet build -c release locally -- they all work but this fails in azure devops -- any idea why?

[image: Here is a link to build output]
[image: here is a link to my main]
[image: link to my project settings]
[image: output from dotnet build - on the same project in release mode locally]

Comment: what agents are you using in CI

Comment: the standard .net core pipeline --

Comment: 1) Is the agent a hosted agent? 2) Did you run the dotnet build command locally as well?

Comment: yes I ran the agent hosted in azure devops -- and that is where the failure is coming from -- when I run locally it works like a champ

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue with my .net core 2.2 console application during compile in my local pc. I am using async in Main. Adding Latest in csproj file worked for me.
This may be helpful building in Azure DevOps, however I haven't tried in Azure DevOps.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
```